# Problem Finding Maximum From AIME (Number Theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization

$m$,$n$,$p$ are natural numbers.
$2mnp=(m+2)(n+2)(p+2)$
$m\leq n\leq p$

then, find the maximum value of $p$.

the source of this question is 1998 AIME.
but the official solution is too long and not easy to get for me.
so I'm searching another solutions.

Comment: Unless you give us more details about what the proof you dislike is, it is hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force will work.

We rewrite it as $$2=\left(1+\frac{2}{m}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{p}\right)$$

Now $2>1+2/m > \sqrt[3]{2}> 1 + 1/4$. Thus $2<m<8$.

You can then do case-by-case analysis. For example, if $m=3$, then you are trying to solve:

$$\frac{6}{5} = \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{p}\right)$$

Again, since $6/5 > 1+2/n > \sqrt{6/5}$, you can reduce to trial of finitely many $n$ - specifically, $10<n<21$.

That probably is going to take a fair amount of time to check.

Comment: Just for my own benefit, is the reason why $1+2/m > \sqrt[3]{2}$ because we know that $1 + 2/m$ has to be the largest of the three terms in the product since $m \leq n \leq p$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why. @DennisMeng

Answer (score 1):

My answer is p=130.

There are 4 cases to consider:

1) $m=1$. Solving for $p$ we get
$$
p =-\frac{6\,n+12}{n+6}
$$
which is always negative. So $m \neq 1$.

2) $m=2$. Solving for $p$ we get
$$ p = -(n+2) < 0$$
So $m \neq 2$.

3) $m=3$. Solving for $p$ we get
$$
p=\frac{10 n+20}{n-10} = 10 + \frac{120}{n-10}$$
So the largest value of $p$ is when $n=11$. This gives $m=3$, $n=11$, $p=130$

4) $m=4$. Solving for $p$
$$ p = \frac{6 n+12}{n-6} = 6 + \frac{48}{n-6}$$
and the maximum value for $p$ is when $n=7$ and $p=54$

It is not very hard to show that as $m$ increases, the maximum value of $p$ decreases, so
the answer is
$$ m=3,~ n=11, ~ p=130$$

To show that we don't have to look for $m$ beyond $m=4$ establish the following:

1) Solve for $p$ and show that $\frac{dp}{dn} <0$. So we want $n$ as small as possible.

2) Set $n=m$, the smallest value of $n$ and simplify and show that solution to $p$ monotonically decreases for $m$.

I am sure there are simpler ways to show that $m \le 4$